HLS.js Change default audio track client side from the start
I want to allow user to apply audio modifications to a video, for example, background voice removal. I'm using MUX for storage, and my idea was to add those modified versions as tracks. This way, I keep everything in one place and user (editor) can easily toggle it on/off and the right version will be presented to the viewer.
To make it possible, I need to be able to play video with different audio track from the start.
Does that makes sense, or, the entire idea is bad?
So far I tried
// it works but after 3-4 seconds
hls({
  startLevel: 4,
  audioPreference: { default: false, name: "isolated" }
})

and responding to events like AUDIO_TRACKS_UPDATED, MANIFEST_PARSED, LEVEL_LOADING.
hls.on(Hls.Events.LEVEL_LOADING, (_eventName, data) => {
      // ---- Still runs 3-4 seconds of the old track
      hls.audioTrack = 1

      // ---- This works better, only half a second of noise
      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   hls.audioTrack = 1
      // }, 500)
    })


Responding to events works better, but only if I delay it by 500ms or so. That is still half a second of the wrong track.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-keller-cn52px
When using codesandbox, it works as expected 80% of the time. If I keep refreshing the preview, sometimes I hear blowing machine for half a second before the right audio track is played. If I remove "startLevel", it works 100% of the time. But if I run it on my localhost, no matter if I have startLevel or not, it always plays the wrong track for 3-4 seconds. That makes me believe that this solution is not reliable.
Here is a loom video where I show it off
https://www.loom.com/share/4c87e72284c947d286e15ba40cecc2fd
